# Right Hand Column Does Not Align Properly in IE6/7/8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm new to this but here goes. I have been developing this website http://www.panelmaster.co.uk and i have managed to solve the majority of design problems but one!

If you take a look at the site in IE the right column seems to drop down and is not aligned with the right and centre column. This problem only occurs in IE as upon testing i found it was fine in firefox and safari.

I have provided below the CSS for the website.

I would appreciate if you guys can help me with the problem.

Thanks in advance. :)

==========================

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
    background-image: url(images/templatemo_body_top.jpg);
    background-color: #90857c;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    text-align: left;
}

a:link, a:visited { color: #073475; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; } 
a:active, a:hover { color: #073475; text-decoration: underline; }

h3 {
    color: #1e7da9;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    color: #1e7da9;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
    color: #696969;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

img { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; }

.cleaner { clear: both; width: 100%; height: 0px; font-size: 0px;  }
.cleaner_h30 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 30px; }
.cleaner_h40 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 40px; }

.float_l { float: left; }
.float_r { float: right; }

.margin_r20 { margin-right: 20px; }

#templatemo_body_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/templatemo_body_bottom.png) repeat-x bottom center;
}

#templatemo_wrapper {
    width: 970px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(images/templatemo_wrapper_top.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}

/* header */

#templatemo_header {
    clear: both;
    width:  890px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 40px
}

#templatemo_header  #site_title {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#site_title a {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#site_title a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;  
    text-decoration: none;
}

#site_title a span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}


/* end of header */

/* menu */

#templatemo_menu {
    clear: both;
    width: 970px;
    height: 80px;
    background: url(images/templatemo_menubar.png) no-repeat;
}

#search_box {
    width: 990px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: right;
}

#search_box form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 40px;
}

#search_box #input_field {
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#search_box #submit_btn {
    height: 24px;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    white-space: pre;
    outline: none;
    color:#666666;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#templatemo_menu ul {
    width: 890px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 40px;
    list-style: none;
}

#templatemo_menu ul li {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

#templatemo_menu ul li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;    
    font-weight: normal;
    outline: none;
}
#templatemo_menu ul li a:hover, #templatemo_menu ul .current {
    color: #162127;
}

/* end of menu */

/* contetnt */

#templatemo_content_wrapper {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px 0; 
}

#templatemo_content {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 550px;
}

#banner {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#templatemo_content #content_top {
    width: 550px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(images/templatemo_content_top.png) no-repeat;
}

#templatemo_content #content_bottom {
    width: 550px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(images/templatemo_content_bottom.png) no-repeat;
}

#templatemo_content #content_middle {
    width: 510px;
    padding: 5px 20px 0px 20px;
    background: url(images/templatemo_content_middle.png) repeat-y;
}

#content_middle p {
    text-align: justify;
}

.templatemo_sidebar_wrapper {
    width: 200px;
}

.templatemo_sidebar {
    width: 197px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    background: url(images/templatemo_sidebar_middle.png) repeat-y;
}

.templatemo_sidebar_top {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(images/templatemo_sidebar_top.png) no-repeat;
}

.templatemo_sidebar_bottom {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(images/templatemo_sidebar_bottom.png) no-repeat;
}

.templatemo_sidebar .sidebar_box {
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar_box1 {
    padding: 15px;

}
.sidebar_box h2 {
    color: #2d84ad;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
    background: url(images/templatemo_sidebar_h1.jpg) left center no-repeat;
}

.sidebar_box .sidebar_box_content {
    padding: 15px;
    background: url(images/templatemo_sidebar_box_top.png) top repeat-x;
}

.sidebar_box img {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.sidebar_box .discount {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar_box .discount span {
    color: #C00;
}

.left_sidebar_box .discount a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}

.sidebar_box .categories_list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.categories_list li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.categories_list li a {
    display: block;
    color: #201f1c;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
    background: url(images/list.png) center left no-repeat;
}
.categories_list li a:hover {
    color: #439ac3;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.news_box {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.news_box h4 {
    padding: 2px 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.news_box h4 a {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #1893f2;
}

#newsletter_box label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#newsletter_box .input_field {
    height: 20px;
    width: 155px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: normal;
}

#newsletter_box .submit_btn {
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 3px 0 15px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    white-space: pre;
    outline: none;
}

.product_box {
    float: left;
    width: 223px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}

.product_box img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.product_box h3 {
    color: #2a2522;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.product_box p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.product_box p span {
    color: #cf5902;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.product_box .detail {
    float: right;
}

.product_box .addtocard {
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background: url(images/templatemo_shopping_cart.png) bottom right no-repeat;
}
/* end of content */

/* footer */

#templatemo_footer_wrapper {
    background: url(images/templatemo_footer.png) repeat-x;
}

#templatemo_footer {
    width: 910px;
    height: 85px;
    padding: 50px 40px 30px 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #a9a098;
}

#templatemo_footer a {
    color: #d7d1cc;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#templatemo_footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFF33;
}

#templatemo_footer .footer_menu {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.footer_menu li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d1cc;
}

.footer_menu li a {
    color: #d7d1cc;
}

.footer_menu .last_menu {
    border: none;
}




/* end of footer */

/*twitter*/

#twitter_div {border-top: 0px;}

#twitter_div a {color: #0000ff !important;}

#twitter_update_list {margin-left: -1em !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important;}

#twitter_update_list li {list-style-type: none; padding-right: 5px; }

#twitter_update_list li a {color: #0000ff; padding-right: 5px;}

#twitter_div {border-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top:6px; padding-right: 5px;}

#twitter_div a, #twitter_update_list li a {text-decoration: none !important;}

#twitter_div a:hover, #twitter_update_list li a:hover {text-decoration:underline !important;}
```

Comment: Including "URGENT" in the title just decreases the chances of getting a response

Comment: This belongs on DocType (http://doctype.com/).

Comment: Also, failing to properly format your code (indent code with four spaces) makes it nigh illegible.

Comment: It would also help if you were to try and mock up a lighter version of the page. Try something that just has the main elements and omit ALL THE PICTURES AND SUPERFLUOUS TEXT. That way we can help you focus on the style-structure and we can ignore the content. Since that's what CSS is for.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the DIV with the class "templatemo_sidebar_wrapper" inside the DIV with the class "templatemo_content_wrapper".

On another note, there is quite a bit wrong with your site. I'm not trying to frustrate you or put you down, but you really should invest a serious amount of time into learning web design. It took me about 1 minute and 45 seconds to load your site which has a footprint of almost 10MB. This is extremely unacceptable by any standard. I would highly recommend switching to [www.squarespace.com](http://www.squarespace.com) or something similar. I can tell you right now that it would cost more money to have a web design company fix your site than it would to have them design one from the ground up.

In its current state, your website will likely hurt your business more than it will help. Good luck.

**Edit:** Move "templatemo_sidebar_wrapper float_r" inside "templatemo_content_wrapper" (I'm not sure this is going to work...you have a lot going on on this page). Your code currently looks like this:

```
<div id="templatemo_content_wrapper">
    <div class="templatemo_sidebar_wrapper float_l"></div>
    <div id="templatemo_content"></div>
    <div id="content_bottom"></div>
</div>


<div class="templatemo_sidebar_wrapper float_r"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Bryan, but i dont quite get what you mean in terms of moving the DIV.